# nginx logs are out of order, probably due to buffered logging

Tags: nginx

Records in my nginx log file are out of order. (Edit: by "out of order" I mean chronologically. e.g. Log lines for 2017-02-21 09:13:26 will often be **before** lines for 2017-02-21 09:13:45) Perhaps a certain amount of out of order records are to be expected because they are logged after a request is completed, not when received. But this is a way higher number of requests that are being logged out of order, including known short (fast) requests for small static files.

Is this a known side effect of using buffered logging or can this be improved?

For getting a more complete picture, here are some other config params:

In `nginx.conf`:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
```

In the config file for the virtual host:

```
server {
    #The backlog parameter matches sysctl net.core.somaxconn setting. Default value is 511 on Ubuntu.
    listen 80 backlog=30000;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=128k;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root   /var/www/html/website;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not too sure why is this an issue...

Comment: What do you mean by "out of order"?  Do the log timestamps go backwards sometimes, or do the logged URLs occur in an order that doesn't match what you were expecting, or something else?  Buffering should not affect the ordering. It only causes the server to accumulate a large number of messages in memory so that they can be pushed to the log file in a single large write, which is more efficient than writing out individual messages.

Comment: @ottomeister I meant the lines are not sorted by time, like you would expect a log file to be usually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's buffering issue. If you are using few workers - each worker has own buffer.

Ways to improve:

- disable buffering
- decrease buffer size (1)
- add `flush` options, if
  flush to disk still rare
- create own log collector with sorting
  (nginx can syslog protocol, for example)

But usually you don't need to care about order of log records. Log analytic systems will sort it by self.

(1) For linux systems buffer size must not exceed the size of an atomic write to a disk file. In modern linux - it's 64k. Well, I'm not 100% sure about this size because information very discrepant. But if you will find broke lines in log - decrease this size.